# AngularJS template function in directive giving error 'Template for directive must have exactly one root element'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I am working on an angular application. for a certain directive, I use the template function like this:

```
template: function(element, attr) {
              return '<div class="myClass">/..some HTML here../</div>'
          }
```

However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

> Error: Template for directive must have exactly one root element, was
>   function (element, attr) { ...the function definition goes here }

If I change it to normal key value pair as follows, it works fine.

```
template: '<div class="myClass">/..some HTML here../</div>'
```

I don't understand what's wrong here. The link and compile functions work just fine. Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a plunkr for your problem? Which angular version are you using? and when you pass a function to template, do you have some logic which generates the html>

Comment: @NikhilBhandari I am simply returning the html from the function without using any logic for generating the html although I want to use some `attr` in an `ng-switch`. I'm using angular v1.0.4

Comment: directive template variable need a value.your passing function.If you want to use function.declare that function some where and call it here like  `template:myfunction()`

Comment: I was trying to pass a function to template but it does not work in angular 1.0.4. I think it was introduced in 1.1.4. Check this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/QVdE3xdn3hmcoQ33gj2R?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @saiyan for your help. I will try with your suggestions

Comment: Thanks @NikhilBhandari I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was introduced in a later version of angular 1.1.4. You'll have to upgrade or find a workaround as @saiyan mentioned.

Check this plunkr - [plnkr.co/edit/QVdE3xdn3hmcoQ33gj2R?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVdE3xdn3hmcoQ33gj2R?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

   <head>

    <!-- CHANGE THE ANGULAR VERSION HERE  -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.4/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body >
    <div something></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app
    .directive("something", function () {
        return {
            template: function () {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        }
    })
```